# Spring data query to find 'ManyToMany' String items between 2 tables

Tags: java, csv, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

i have a Spring + Java 11 + H2 in-memory database project and
I have these 2 Entities (about the IMDB datasets) and corresponding Repositories:

**Name:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder    
public class Name
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="nconst")
    private String nconst;

    @Column(name="primaryName")
    private String primaryName;

    @Column(name="birthYear")
    private String birthYear;

    @Column(name="deathYear")
    private String deathYear;

    @Column(name="primaryProfession")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> primaryProfession;

    @Column(name="knownForTitles")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> knownForTitles;
}
```

**Title:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Builder
public class Title
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="tconst")
    private String tconst;

    @Column(name="directors")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> directors;

    @Column(name="writers")
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    private List<String> writers;
}
```

**NameRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface NameRepository extends CrudRepository<Name, String>
{
    Page<Name> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Name findByNconst(String nconst);
    Name findByPrimaryName(String primaryName);
}
```

**TitleRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface TitleRepository extends CrudRepository<Title, String>
{
    Page<Title> findAll(Pageable pageable);
    Title findByTconst(String tconst);
}
```

`knownForTitles` field values of Name entity are `tconst` from the Title entity(FK), which means each Name can have multiple `tconst` and each Title can have multiple `nconst` value for `directors` and `writers` fields that `nconst` is a primary key of table Name, we have ManyToMany relationship here, to demonstrate better please see below:

**Name Dataset Sample:**
[image: Name Dataset Sample]

as you can see item: `nm0085156` from the Name collection has corresponding field in the table Title(it located in `directors` and `writers` fields), it means he is known as one of the crew for the title `nm0085156` :

**Title Dataset Sample:**

[image: Title Dataset Sample]

Well, i want to write a query to find all items from table Title(one or more) that the `nm0085156` is director and writer or just director/writers for that title, it means i should find this field/fields :

[image: QueryResult]

I wanted to use `@Query` and `@ManyToMany` JPA annotation to write a custom query for that but i have this error:

```
'Many To Many' attribute value type should not be 'String'
```

Could you please guide me?

Comment: Looks like you need some join tables and look up how @ManyToMany with join tables works.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz hi, i know i have a ManyToMany case and i need a table joining, but i can't find a solution to write a proper query for this situation